# How to only unify with a non blank tail in a list?

Tags: prolog

To unify with single element lists you do `[_]`. How do you unify with lists that have more than 1 element? Since `[_|_]` will still unify with `[1]`.

For example, I want to know if it is possible to unify with `[1,2]` but not with `[1]`.

I need this because I want to use `delete(Lst1,[_|_] (if this worked), Lst2)`, to remove all multiple-element lists from Lst1.

Right now to accomplish this I have to first remove all single-element lists from Lst1 to get a list with all the multiple-element lists, then remove that list from Lst1 to get a list with all the single-element lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term `[_,_|_]` unifies with lists that have at least 2 elements:

```
   ?- [1]=[_,_|_].
no
   ?- [1,2]=[_,_|_].
yes
   ?- [1,2,3]=[_,_|_].
yes
```

Concerning your plan to use it with subtract/3, consider the following queries:

```
?- subtract([[1],[2,3],[4],[2,3]],[[_,_|_]], Lst2).
Lst2 = [[1], [4]].
```

This seems to be what you want to do but if `[_,_|_]` is unified with `[2,3]`:

```
?- subtract([[1],[2,3],[4],[5,6]],[[_,_|_]], Lst2).
Lst2 = [[1], [4], [5, 6]].
```

Are you by any chance trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727509/6101159)?

Comment: Works with delete, delete([[1],[2,3],[4],[5,6]],[_,_|_], Lst2). Thanks!